# How can I loop through arrays for different users in a database and generate users with same dates?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database similar to this.

```
[
  {
    name: 'Ben Smith',
    age: 24,
    dutyDates: [2020 - 12 - 06, 2020 - 11 - 21, 2020 - 10 - 11],
    role: 'staff',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Harris',
    age: 19,
    dutyDates: [2020 - 11 - 21, 2020 - 09 - 14, .........],
    role: 'staff',
  },
  {
    name: 'Dwayne Jones',
    age: 36,
    dutyDates: [2020 - 06 - 15, 2020 - 12 - 12, .........],
    role: 'staff',
  },
  ......
];
```

It is a mongodb mongoose database. Using nodejs, How can I query the database to generate users with same dates in the array.

For Instance, If I query `2020 - 11 - 21` How can I get users ben and Jane since both have same dates in their array. I am using nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple find query if you are storing the dates in the array as strings, check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c_EpB0Sx5bc) for more info

```
db.collection.find({
  dutyDates: "2020 - 11 - 21"
})
```